# php microtime() behaving differently

Tags: php, microtime

I'm working with an API which calculates a timestamp using the following function:

```
public function timestamp() {
  return round(microtime(TRUE) * 1000);
}
```

But when i call the function on my localhost and on my webhost, i get the following in return:

1.37872612307E+12

But if i get other people to run the same code on their server(and using http://writecodeonline.com/php/), i get the following, and correct timestamp back:

1378726142452

But why?

Running XAMPP on OSX, and on unoeuro.com webhost.

Comment: It's strange since code works fine - see this [snippet](http://3v4l.org/r5W5S)

Comment: Can be precision-setting in php.ini? E+12 just means *(10^12), so the real number is 1378726123070. I don't know how PHP calculates this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @FrederikSpang comment

You can set `precision` setting in `php.ini` file. It should be greater than yours(14)

For ex my ini setting is `16`:

```
precision = 16
```

Comment: That did it! Strange!

Answer (score 1):

Check `precision` setting in your `php.ini`.

See how different values influence on output of your function: http://ideone.com/9MMLvD